# Encryption in SQL (SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt particular data I wish in the tables..

For example,

I need something like this:

```
update mytable set column1 = encrypt(column1, "key") where condition;
```

and this:

```
select decrypt(column1, "key") from mytable where condition;
```

> Is threre any simple in-built SQL function in **SQLite** to accomplish
>   this?

I have a Java function for encrypt() and decrypt(), I need to bulk encrypt the table column and it will be too slow if I read the column, apply the function and then write back. Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean sqlite3 would be too slow for production? I think sqlite3 is a one of the greatest tools -- for development. For production I'd use another RDBMS, like Postgres or MySQL. The latter for example comes with some encryption functions built-in: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has possibility to supply your own functions - create_function sqlite function - that you can than use in the SQL statement.

So I would look for create_function in java, e.g:
http://ppewww.physics.gla.ac.uk/~tdoherty/sqlite/javasqlite-20050608/doc/SQLite/Database.html
or here is even an example
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/221260

For Example, in python it looks like this (example taken from http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html Connection.create_function)

```
import sqlite3
import md5

def md5sum(t):
    return md5.md5(t).hexdigest()

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.create_function("md5", 1, md5sum)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select md5(?)", ("foo",))
print cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Or: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html

Comment: I am using Java. Could you please check the first link. It throws a 404.